# Is there a way to extend a Blazor component to add custom properties?

Tags: blazor, blazor-component

I need to dynamically control whether a component is rendered to the page. I know I can just wrap things in an `@if` block, but I think adding an `IsVisible` property to an existing component would be cleaner.

**Update**

I'll rephrase the question and add some context.

My users want to select which fields are visible. I will show them a dialog where they can select which fields they want. Their preferences will be stored in a database. I was hoping to extend the component to control its visibility. I actually did create a wrapper component, but it has it seems hacky and not much better than a simple `@if` block. Here is a simple working example for toggling fields.

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wOQRafwxfwppEuyo

Comment: You can't directly.  Components are classes and you can't extend classes with properties.  You also can't add such functionality easily to `ComponentBase` as it wasn't designed for wrapper functionality.  That said, you can create wrapper components for those you want to hide, or go wild and move away from `ComponentBase` [which is what I do].  Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit a component they are just a C# class. To avoid the Razor compiler do not use the `.razor` extension.

`SomeComponentExtended.cs`

```cs
public class SomeComponentExtended : SurveyPrompt
{
    [Parameter]
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        if (IsVisible)
        {
            base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
        }
    }
}
```